# Update Records from CSV TestClass

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm running into an issue where my code coverage is lower than I'd like.  I've hit a wall where the lines of the controller in the image below are not covered.  I'm not sure how to get those lines to be covered via the test class.  Does anyone have any advice?

UseCaseSummary: Via visualforce page, insert csv file > call controller to process csv content

***Visualforce***

```
    <apex:page controller="updateLeads" > <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <style type="text/css">
        #title{font-size: 150%;margin-left: 40%;}
        input {padding-top: 0;width: 100%;}
        table.detailList {width: 50% !important;text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;}
        </style>
        <h2 id="title">Update Lead Records</h2><br/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="BEFORE UPLOADING, please confirm that your upload file is formatted as follows:" style="color: red;font-weight:bold;padding:50px"></apex:outputText><br/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="● Column A contains the Lead Id(s)" style="color: red;font-weight:bold;padding:100px;list-style-type: circle"></apex:outputText><br/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="● Column B contains Reseller Id(s)" style="color: red;font-weight:bold;padding:100px"></apex:outputText><br/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="● File Type is .csv" style="color: red;font-weight:bold;padding:100px"></apex:outputText><br/><br/>

            <apex:form > 
                <apex:pagemessages />
                <apex:pageBlock >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"> 
                        <apex:inputFile value="{!csvFileBody}"  filename="{!csvAsString}"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Update Leads" action="{!updateLeads}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
                 </apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlock >
                 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                   <apex:facet name="header">Successes</apex:facet>
                      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leadsToUpdateSuccess}" var="ldSuccess" title="Success">
                        <apex:column headerValue="X18_digit_id__c"><apex:outputLink value="/{!ldSuccess.X18_digit_id__c}" target="_blank" >{!ldSuccess.X18_digit_id__c}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Reseller__c" value="{!ldSuccess.ResellerId__c}"/>
                     </apex:pageBlockTable>
                 </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                     <apex:facet name="header">Errors</apex:facet>
                     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leadsToUpdateError}" var="ldError" title="Error">
                        <apex:column headerValue="X18_digit_id__c"><apex:outputLink value="/{!ldError.X18_digit_id__c}" target="_blank">{!ldError.X18_digit_id__c}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Reseller__c" value="{!ldError.ResellerId__c}"/>
                     </apex:pageBlockTable>
                 </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form> 
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

***Controller***

```
public class updateLeads {
    
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
Public string csvAsString{get;set;}
Public String[] csvfilelines{get;set;}
Public List <Lead> sObjectList {get;set;}
public List <Lead> leadsToUpdateSuccess {get;set;}
public List <Lead> leadsToUpdateError {get;set;}
Public String userName {get;set;} 

    
    
public updateLeads()
   {
    csvfilelines = new String[]{};
    sObjectList = New List<Lead>();
    leadsToUpdateSuccess = New List<Lead>();
    leadsToUpdateError = New List<Lead>();

   }
    Public void updateLeads(){
      
        User currentUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userinfo.getUserId()];
        userName = currentUser.Name;
        csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
        csvfilelines = csvAsString.split('\n');
        

       for(Integer i=1;i<csvfilelines.size();i++)
           try{
         {
           string[] csvRecordData = csvfilelines[i].split(',');
           String LeadId = csvRecordData[0];
           String ResellerId = csvRecordData[1];
             System.debug('LeadId: '+LeadId);
             System.debug('ResellerId: '+ResellerId);
           String LeadIdNormalized = LeadId.normalizeSpace();
           String ResellerIdNormalized = ResellerId.normalizeSpace();
             System.debug('LeadId: '+LeadIdNormalized);
             System.debug('ResellerId: '+ResellerIdNormalized);
           Lead lObj = new Lead();
             System.debug(lObj);
           lObj.Id = Id.valueOf(LeadIdNormalized);
             System.debug(lObj);
           lObj.Reseller__c = Id.valueOf(ResellerIdNormalized);
             System.debug(lObj);
           sObjectList.add(lObj);
             System.debug('List: '+sObjectList);

            }


       }
                
        catch(Exception e)  
              {
                ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'NOTE: all Leads that did not result in an error were successfully updated.  Error Message: '+e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
              }
            List<Database.SaveResult> srList = Database.update(sObjectList, false);
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList){
                if(sr.isSuccess()){
                    System.debug('Successfully updated Lead. Lead Id: '+sr.getId());
                    leadsToUpdateSuccess = [Select Id, X18_digit_id__c, Reseller__c, ResellerId__c, LastModifiedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Lead WHERE Id IN:sObjectList AND LastModifiedBy.Name = :userName AND LastModifiedDate = TODAY AND Reseller__c != NULL];
                    System.debug('leadsToUpdate: '+leadsToUpdateSuccess);
                }
                else{
                    for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()){
                        System.debug('The following error has occurred.');
                        System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': '+err.getMessage());
                        System.debug('Lead fields that affected this error: '+err.getFields());
                        leadsToUpdateError = [Select Id, X18_digit_id__c, Reseller__c, ResellerId__c, Name FROM Lead WHERE Id IN:sObjectList AND Reseller__c = NULL];
                        System.debug('leadsToUpdate: '+leadsToUpdateError);
                        ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Some of the Leads were not updated, due to the following error.  Error Message: '+err.getMessage()+' | '+err.getFields());
                        ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
                                                                    

                    }
                     
                }

            }

        }
        
    }
```

***TestClass***

```
@isTest
public class updateLeadsTest {

public static Blob csvFileBody;
public static String[] csvFileLines;
Public static string csvAsString;


testMethod static void testSubmit() {
    String gsRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Channel Partner').getRecordTypeId();
    Account testResellerAcct = new Account (Name='Test', ShippingCountry='United States',RecordTypeId=gsRecordTypeID);
    insert testResellerAcct;
    system.debug(testResellerAcct);
    String ResellerId = Id.valueOf(testResellerAcct.id);
    Lead testLead = new Lead (LastName = 'Test', Email = 'test@test.com', Company = 'Test', Status = 'New');
    insert testLead;
    system.debug(testLead);
    String LeadId = Id.valueOf(testLead.Id);
    String str = 'x18_digit_id__c,Reseller__c,'+LeadId+','+ResellerId;
    system.debug('str: '+str);
    csvFileBody = Blob.valueOf(str);
    system.debug('csvFileBody: '+csvFileBody);
    csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
    system.debug('csvAsString: '+csvAsString);
    csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
    system.debug('csvFilesLines: '+csvFileLines);
    updateLeads con = new updateLeads();
    con.csvFileBody = csvFileBody;
    con.csvAsString = csvAsString;
    con.csvfilelines = csvFileLines;
    con.updateLeads();
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made couple changes to your test class and getting 89% code coverage.
Created one more test Lead record (testLead1) to throw exception.

```
@isTest
public class updateLeadsTest {

public static Blob csvFileBody;
public static String[] csvFileLines;
Public static string csvAsString;


testMethod static void testSubmit() {
    ID gsRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Channel Partner').getRecordTypeId();
    Account testResellerAcct = new Account (Name='Test', ShippingCountry='United States',RecordTypeID = gsRecordTypeID);
    insert testResellerAcct;
    system.debug(testResellerAcct);
    String ResellerId = Id.valueOf(testResellerAcct.id);
    Lead testLead = new Lead (LastName = 'Test', Email = 'test@test.com', Company = 'Test', Status = 'New');
    insert testLead;
    Lead testLead1 = new Lead (LastName = 'Test1', Email = 'test@test1.com', Company = 'Test1', Status = 'New1');
    insert testLead1;// this lead is to create Exception 
    system.debug(testLead);
    String LeadId = Id.valueOf(testLead.Id);
    String str = 'x18_digit_id__c,Reseller__c'+'\n'+LeadId+','+ResellerId; //Added '\n' delimiter to split str into multiple lines 
    str += '\n'+testLead1.id+','+'ResellerId'; //Since 'ResellerId' is a string it cannot be converted to Id and it will throw exception.
    system.debug('str: '+str);
    csvFileBody = Blob.valueOf(str);
    
    
    system.debug('csvFileBody: '+csvFileBody);
    csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
    system.debug('csvAsString: '+csvAsString);
    csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
    system.debug('csvFilesLines: '+csvFileLines);
    updateLeads con = new updateLeads();
    con.csvFileBody = csvFileBody;
    con.csvAsString = csvAsString;
    con.csvfilelines = csvFileLines;
    con.updateLeads();
}
}
```

```
else{
for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()){
}
} // Since this is in Exception catch block its not covering with current test data. Exception happening before adding Lead to list - sObjectList
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pkr -- The Community tends to prefer answers that elaborate a bit on what you did and why rather than just code

Comment: The comments in the code elaborate enough, thank you!